# Join two sql tables using multiple possible combinations

Tags: sql

I need a way to join two tables that can handle the case where the default join method fails.

Lets say I have two tables, Customers with the fields you'd expect

| CustomerId | First Name | Last Name | DOB | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | 01/01/2000 | 1 Main Street |

And Orders

| OrderId | CustomerId | Customer FName | Customer LName | Delivery Address | Other Order Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5054 | 1 | John | Smith | 1 Main Street | blah |

The obvious way to join these two tables is on Customer Id.

However, how do I structure a query so that in the case when there is no matching Customer Id, it switches to a second join method, i.e. on address, then if that fails, another fall back of First Name + Last Name (I know that's a bad join but roll with it for this example)

Thanks

Comment: You set up a foreign key constraint to guarantee that every order has a customer.

Comment: It pains me, but unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
with
    first_q as (
    SELECT
        c.CustomerId    as customer_id
        ,o.OrderId      as order_id
    FROM
                Customers   AS c
        join    Orders      AS o
            on  c.CustomerId  = o.CustomerId 
    )
    ,second_q   as (
    SELECT
        c.CustomerId    as customer_id
        ,o.OrderId      as order_id
    FROM
                Customers   AS c
        join    Orders      AS o
            on  c.[Address] = o.[Delivery Address]
    WHERE
        o.OrderId NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM first_q)
    )
    ,third_q    as (
    SELECT
        c.CustomerId    as customer_id
        ,o.OrderId      as order_id
    FROM
                Customers   AS c
        join    Orders      AS o
            on  concat(c.[First Name], ' ', c.[Last Name]) = concat(o.[Customer FName], ' ', o.[Customer LName])
    WHERE
            o.OrderId NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM first_q)
        and o.OrderId NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM second_q)
    )
SELECT
    customer_id
    ,order_id
FROM
    first_q
UNION
SELECT
    customer_id
    ,order_id
FROM
    second_q
UNION
SELECT
    customer_id
    ,order_id
FROM
    third_q
;
```

Assuming that there might be multiple matches by the two latter joins, I would add some ranking functions to retrieve only the first result by OrderId.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered using a cte for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use a CTE where the default join method fails, you can handle the scenario with alternative join conditions, you can use left joins with coalesce statements to prioritize the join conditions. I would try

```
SELECT
    o.OrderId,
    o.CustomerId,
    COALESCE(c.FirstName, c2.FirstName) AS FirstName,
    COALESCE(c.LastName, c2.LastName) AS LastName,
    COALESCE(c.DOB, c2.DOB) AS DOB,
    COALESCE(c.Address, c2.Address) AS Address,
    o.[Delivery Address],
    o.[Other Order Info]
FROM
    Orders AS o
LEFT JOIN
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN
    Customers AS c2 ON o.[Delivery Address] = c2.Address
        AND c.CustomerId IS NULL
LEFT JOIN
    Customers AS c3 ON o.[Customer FName] = c3.FirstName
        AND o.[Customer LName] = c3.LastName
        AND c.CustomerId IS NULL
        AND c2.Address IS NULL;
```

I performed left joins on the **Customers** table multiple times with different join conditions. The **COALESCE** function is used to select the first non-null value for each respective field.

The first left join attempts to join on the default condition **o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId**.

If the first join fails (**c.CustomerId IS NULL**), the second left join tries to match the address **o.[Delivery Address] = c2.Address**.

If both the first and second join fails (**c.CustomerId IS NULL and c2.Address IS NULL**), the third left join falls back to the join condition using the first name and last name **o.[Customer FName] = c3.FirstName and o.[Customer LName] = c3.LastName**.

In this way, the query will try different join conditions in sequence and return the first non-null values from the matching rows.

Comment: Nice, this is more what i had in my head but couldn't figure out the best method. Cheers!